# What is the best material for a flat heated surface

Tags: material-science

I am facing an application where I need to find a plate material that is very flat ( < 400microns per m flatness) 
And can resist temperature up to 200C while being lightweight and resiste thermal chocs. Most ceramics have trouble with this, unless there are some I don't know about, my knowledge in the area lacks

Metal plates tend to curve easily, so that wouldn't work.

A part from boroscilicate glass. Does such a material exist?